# Interrupt conditional cumulative sum pandas python

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have the following dataframe with attempted spendings (or transactions) from different users, every attempt has a date and an amount.

```
user  date amount
1     1    6    
1     2    5    
1     3    2    
1     4    3    
1     5    1    
2     1    11    
2     2    12    
2     3    5    
2     4    8    
2     5    1
```

Let's say I want to impose an arbitrary limit to the total amount spent and check which transactions go through (because the user isn't surpassing the limit) and which ones do not, let's say the limit is 10.
The desired result would be:

```
user  date amount approved spent remaining_credit
1     1    6      1        6     4
1     2    5      0        6     4
1     3    2      1        8     2
1     4    3      0        8     2
1     5    1      1        9     1
2     1    11     0        0     10
2     2    12     0        0     10
2     3    5      1        5     5
2     4    8      0        5     5
2     5    1      1        6     4
```

Anyway to calculate any of the 3 last columns works to solve my problem.
The first one (approved, col number 4) would have a 1 each time the amount of the operation is less than the limit minus the sum of the amount spent prevoiusly.
The second one (spent) has the cumulative spending of the approved transactions.
The third one (remaing_credit) has the remaining credit after each attempted spending.
I tried with:

```
d1['spent'] = d1.sort_values('date').groupby('user')['amount'].cumsum()
d1['spent'] = d1.sort_values(['user','date']).spent.mask(d1.spent > limit).fillna(method='pat')
```

but then I don't know how to restart the cumulative sum when the limit isn't surpassed again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This can be done by creating your own function in which you will iterate through the data to create each column, then `groupby.apply`:

```
def calcul_spendings (ser, val_max=1):
    arr_am = ser.to_numpy()
    arr_sp = np.cumsum(arr_am)
    arr_ap = np.zeros(len(ser))
    for i in range(len(arr_am)):
        if arr_sp[i]>val_max: # check if the 
            arr_sp[i:] -= arr_am[i]
        else:
            arr_ap[i] = 1
    return pd.DataFrame({'approved':arr_ap, 
                         'spent': arr_sp, 
                         'remaining_credit':val_max-arr_sp}, 
                        index=ser.index)

df[['approved','spent','remaining_credit']] = df.sort_values('date').groupby('user')['amount'].apply(calcul_spendings, val_max=10)
print (df)
   user  date  amount  approved  spent  remaining_credit
0     1     1       6       1.0      6                 4
1     1     2       5       0.0      6                 4
2     1     3       2       1.0      8                 2
3     1     4       3       0.0      8                 2
4     1     5       1       1.0      9                 1
5     2     1      11       0.0      0                10
6     2     2      12       0.0      0                10
7     2     3       5       1.0      5                 5
8     2     4       8       0.0      5                 5
9     2     5       1       1.0      6                 4
```